# What happens to the beast knights' animals after the ring holder dies?

Tags: hoshi-no-samidare

In Lucifer and the Biscuit Hammer, some human beast knights die. What happens to the animal avatar when that happens?

The dog knight is not mentioned anywhere else, but during the swordfish knight, it is stated that the swordfish stayed besides the body for some time.

Comment: I tagged it with the Japanese title, because the english title is longer than 25 characters and I could not abbreviate it adequately. If you can come with a good english tag name, feel free to improve it.